# Element of minimal distance to a convex, closed cone: orthogonality?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $C\subseteq H$ a convex, norm-closed cone. Let $\xi \in H$. There is a unique $\eta \in C$ such that $\|\xi-\eta\| = d(\xi, C)$ (= the minimal distance of $\xi$ to $C$). Moreover, $\xi-\eta \perp \eta$.

I can show the first part of the theorem, namely that $\eta \in C$ exists with $\|\xi-\eta\| = d(\xi, C)$. I am not able to show that $\xi-\eta \perp \eta$ though, i.e. that
$$0 = \langle \xi-\eta, \eta\rangle \iff \langle \xi,\eta\rangle =\|\eta\|^2.$$
Any hints or answers for this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: It is not true, take $C= \{ (x,y) | x \ge 0, y \ge 0 \}$ and $\xi = (-1,-1)$. Then $\eta = (0,0)$. I think the best you can say is that $\langle \xi-\eta, c-\eta \rangle \le 0$ for all $c \in C$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks! I hope the statement is correct now. At least it survives your counterexample now, and is sufficient for the application I have in mind.

Comment: That's simply not true in complex Hilbert spaces. For example, take $H=\mathbb C$, $C=i\mathbb R_+$ and $\xi=1+i$. Then $\eta=i$ and $\langle\xi-\eta,\eta\rangle=i$ (or $-i$, depending on the definition of the inner product).

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you! The question is asked because Takesaki uses this in Lemma 1.7 in his second volume on p148. Maybe Takesaki's proof contains a flaw then? If you can adress this, I would be more than happy to give you the bounty :)

Comment: But the crucial fact in this case is that $J\xi=\xi$. So he applies this result to the *real* Hilbert space $\ker(J-1)$, and copper.hat's answer applies.

Comment: @MaoWao Do you want to turn this into an answer? I will give you the bounty and accept the other answer, if that is ok to you.

Comment: No. This may have been your actual question, but is really not the question you first asked here. So I think it's best to give copper.hat the bounty for his answer, and I'll add the complex counterexample as a second answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider cones inside complex Hilbert spaces (which is often not done because of pathologies like this), then the result is not necessarily true. For example, if $H=\mathbb C$ (as complex Hilbert space with inner product $\langle z,w\rangle=\overline z w$), $C=i\mathbb R_+$ and $\xi=1+i$, then $\eta=i$ and $\langle \xi-\eta,\eta\rangle=i\neq 0$.

Comment: Looks like a valid counterexample in the complex case

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to show that the nearest point $\eta \in C$ to $\xi$, where $C$ is a closed convex set, satisfies $\langle \xi-\eta, c-\eta \rangle \le 0$ for all $c \in C$.

If $C$ is also a cone, then $c=\lambda \eta \in C$ for all $\lambda \ge 0$ and so
$(\lambda -1) \langle \xi-\eta, \eta \rangle \le 0$ for all $\lambda \ge 0$. Hence $\langle \xi-\eta, \eta \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Hi. Can you elaborate why this inequality ib the beginning of your answer is true? Thanks!

Comment: See Theorem 4 in https://www.princeton.edu/~aaa/Public/Teaching/ORF523/S16/ORF523_S16_Lec7_gh.pdf applied fo $f(\eta) =  {1 \over 2} \| \eta-\xi \|^2$.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I don't see how this theorem helps, as it only works for $\mathbb{R}^n$. The crux of the argument relies on something I don't understand, which seems a bit problematic to me. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: The result holds in a Hilbert space. Draw a little picture to get some intuitive idea of why it is true.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I still don't get it. Does this answer assume that the Hilbert space in question is real? Because it is not clear to me why $\langle \xi-\eta, c-\eta\rangle \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: See https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/17/254a-notes-5-hilbert-spaces/comment-page-1/ for an appropriate modification for complex spaces.

Comment: Thanks, this shows that you have to replace the inner product $\langle \xi-\eta, c-\eta\rangle$ in your answer by its real part. Accordingly, you end up with $\Re \langle \xi-\eta, \eta\rangle= 0$. But the original question is why is $\xi-\eta \perp \eta$, which remains unanswered (in the complex case).

Comment: Good point. I will need to investigate more.